# Is there any method to shows sent email in the Sent Mailbox using MailApp Google Sheet Apps Script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use MailApp by Google Apps Script in Google Sheets to send bulk emails and I found that after successfully send out the message, it doesn't shows in the Sent of my mailbox

Can I know is there any method to let it to shows in my mailbox under Sent too? because I would like check is my mails really being sent though it already remark EMAIL_SENT

and also sometimes may need to forward or reply under same email sent

[image]

the codes is from this link:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2]; // Third column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Once the email sent successfully using this script it makes a copy in the Sent folder.. if you are not getting a copy of the mail in the Sent folder it means your mail is not sent

Comment: @DevenRamani But I test with my own email, recipient email received the email but no mail shows in the Sent folder

Comment: can you post your script here for better understanding

Comment: @DevenRamani i edited in the questions, you may have a look

Comment: sorry, but using the same script I'm getting sent copy in my sent folder

Comment: @BBBBBBBB: is your account the account that installed/authorized the script?

Comment: @JPV u mean the owner of the google sheet?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, sent emails are showing up in the `Sent` folder. Most likely the account with which you are executing the script (that is, the one that is sending the emails), is not the same as the account whose `Sent` folder in Gmail UI you are checking. Can you please double-check that? Maybe you are logged into different accounts?